# Meaning of new Class[0] in Reflection API

Tags: java, class, reflection

I came across a statement:

```
o1 = o1.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0]).invoke(o1, new Object[0]);
```

Can someone please tell me what `new Class[0]` and `new Object[0]` do in this case, where `o1` is any `Object`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getMethod() takes a list of types for arguments. Passing a zero-length array means it has no arguments. Same for invoke().

From the documentation for [`Class.getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29):

> If parameterTypes is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array.

From the documentation for [`Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

> If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying method is 0, the supplied args array may be of length 0 or null.

The line you posted, in that context, then, is equivalent to:

```
o1 = o1.getClass().getMethod(getter, null).invoke(o1, null);
```

Personally I find the use of `null` there to be more readable (although the use of a zero-length array does have the benefit of self-documenting the type of parameter that the programmer is not passing, if that means much to you).

Comment: +1 and it's also equivalent to `o1 = o1.getClass().getMethod(getter).invoke(o1);` now that varargs were added.

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks once again for fixing my documentation links. I have an old, deep-rooted habit of prefacing all Java search terms with "java 6" in Google. (So much so that it makes its way into non-Java searches, e.g. "java 6 chili recipe" and "java 6 how to get rid of house flies".)

Comment: Ha, that made my night :D

Answer (score 2):

```
o1.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0])
```

It means it tells [Class#getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to find a method named `getter` which has **NO** arguments.

Its same as

```
o1.getClass().getMethod(getter, null)
```